# Passing static variables to GNU Parallel

Tags: linux, bash, multithreading, loops, gnu-parallel

In a bash script I am trying to pass multiple distinct fastq files and several user-provided static variables to GNU Parallel. I can't hardcode the static variables because while they do not change within the script, they are set by the user and are variable between uses. I have tried a few different ways but get an error `argument -b/--bin: expected one argument`

Attempt 1:

```
binSize="10000"
outputDir="output"
errors="1"
minReads="10"

ls fastq_F* | parallel "python myscript.py -f split_fastq_F{} -b $binSize -o $outputDir -e $errors -p -t $minReads"
```

Attempt 2:

```
    my_func() {
      python InDevOptimizations/DemultiplexUsingBarcodes_New_V1.py \
             -f split_fastq_F$1 \
             -b $binSize \
             -o $outputDir \
             -e $errors \
             -p \
             -t $minReads
    }
    export -f my_func

    ls fastq_F* | parallel my_func
```

It seems clear that I am not correctly passing the static variables... but I can't seem to grasp what the correct way to do this is.

Comment: Have you considered `export`ing those variables? The error message to me suggests that the content of `$binSize` didn't make it into the call ...

Comment: That is a great idea i will try it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: RESULT:  Eporting seemed to help in the context of "Attempt 2:" however it resulted in a different error "No such file or directory: 'split_fastq_F'" indicating that my changing variable was incorrectly passed to the function.

Comment: UPDATED RESULT: Exporting solved the problem.  The additional issues mentioned above were due to unrelated problems with my implementation.

Comment: I think you'd be safer and more correct to use the style `parallel my_func ::: fastq_F*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try `--dr` when GNU Parallel does not do what you expect.

```
binSize="10000"
outputDir="output"
errors="1"
minReads="10"

ls fastq_F* | parallel --dr "python myscript.py -f split_fastq_F{} -b $binSize -o $outputDir -e $errors -p -t $minReads"
```

You are using " and not ' so the variables should be substituted by the shell before GNU Parallel starts.

If the commands are run locally (i.e. not remote) you can use `export VARIABLE`.

If run on remote servers, use `env_parallel`:

```
env_parallel --session

alias myecho='echo aliases'
env_parallel -S server myecho ::: work
myfunc() { echo functions $*; }
env_parallel -S server myfunc ::: work
myvar=variables
env_parallel -S server echo '$myvar' ::: work
myarray=(arrays work, too)
env_parallel -k -S server echo '${myarray[{}]}' ::: 0 1 2

env_parallel --end-session
```